# Cannot reuse an outlet that does not contain a component

Tags: angular

I am working on Application with parent-child routing (router-outlets and routier-link), I am getting this error intermittenly, Most the time route change works, but sometimes it logs following error in console.

```
EXCEPTION: Cannot reuse an outlet that does not contain a component.t.logError @ angular2.min.js:21t.logGroup @ angular2.min.js:21e.call @ angular2.min.js:3(anonymous function) @ angular2.min.js:19e._onError @ angular2.min.js:10e._createInnerZone.t.onError @ angular2.min.js:10n.run @ angular2.min.js:1e._createInnerZone.e.fork.fork.$run @ angular2.min.js:10n.bind @ angular2.min.js:1k @ angular2.min.js:1A @ angular2.min.js:1I @ angular2.min.js:1(anonymous function) @ angular2.min.js:1r @ angular2.min.js:10n.run @ angular2.min.js:1e._createInnerZone.e.fork.fork.$run @ angular2.min.js:10n.bind @ angular2.min.js:1h @ angular2.min.js:1
angular2.min.js:21 STACKTRACE:t.logError @ angular2.min.js:21e.call @ angular2.min.js:3(anonymous function) @ angular2.min.js:19e._onError @ angular2.min.js:10e._createInnerZone.t.onError @ angular2.min.js:10n.run @ angular2.min.js:1e._createInnerZone.e.fork.fork.$run @ angular2.min.js:10n.bind @ angular2.min.js:1k @ angular2.min.js:1A @ angular2.min.js:1I @ angular2.min.js:1(anonymous function) @ angular2.min.js:1r @ angular2.min.js:10n.run @ angular2.min.js:1e._createInnerZone.e.fork.fork.$run @ angular2.min.js:10n.bind @ angular2.min.js:1h @ angular2.min.js:1
angular2.min.js:21 Error: Cannot reuse an outlet that does not contain a component.
    at new t (angular2.min.js:17)
    at RouterOutlet.reuse (router_outlet.js:83)
    at ChildRouter.Router.commit (router.js:286)
    at router.js:295
    at n.run (angular2.min.js:1)
    at n.e._createInnerZone.e.fork.fork.$run [as run] (angular2.min.js:10)
    at n.bind (angular2.min.js:1)
    at k (angular2.min.js:1)
    at A (angular2.min.js:1)
    at I (angular2.min.js:1)
```

i have searched about this problem [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4228) and [here](https://github.com/angular/router/issues/378) on github but cant understand whats the problem is ?
anyone who knows how to handle this problem ? or is this the any kind of Bug ?

as example here is plnkr having same problem [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8BpIV8v0mNYcKWR85I5b?p=preview)
.

Comment: There are more [issues](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4728) related to this, and it is a bug. I'm not aware of any workaround, you'll have to wait for a fix.

Comment: Yes i had read these issue @EricMartinez. okay ill wait.